# feathersjs application not starting on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, feathersjs

I have an application which I deploy via github actions to heroku.
But it won't start, respectively it doesn't find the compiled sources to start the app.

Unfortunately I'm new to heroku and I can't find what might cause the issue.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "composite": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test"
  ]
}
```

my package.json has the following scripts (I only added the ones that are important to the problem)

```
 "heroku-postbuild": "npm run compile",
 "start": "node lib/",
 "compile": "shx rm -rf lib/ && tsc"
```

heroku's ProcFile (autogenerated) shows the following
`web npm start` (copied from dashboard)

the github action

```
- name: Deploy Backend
        uses: AkhileshNS/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: "the name"
          heroku_email: "example@mail.com"
          appdir: "./server"
        env:
          HD_MONOGDB_CONNECTION: ${{ secrets.MONGODB_CONNECTION }}
          HD_HOST: ${{ secrets.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL }}
          HD_PORT: ${{ secrets.BACKEND_PORT }}
          HD_NODE_ENV: "production"
```

The deployment is ok, I can see the files with the heroku cli.
According to heroku it also builds successfully.

But I see the following error in the logs

```
2022-04-12T10:06:46.016367+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/lib'

2022-04-12T10:06:46.016368+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
2022-04-12T10:06:46.016368+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
2022-04-12T10:06:46.016369+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
2022-04-12T10:06:46.016369+00:00 app[web.1]:     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2022-04-12T10:06:46.016370+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-04-12T10:06:46.016370+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: []
2022-04-12T10:06:46.016371+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Despite telling node via tsconfig to build/compile the code into `./lib` the folder doesn't exist.
It seems that the scripts are run from the correct folder in heroku (`/app`) because I can find a `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` file

EDIT: Added build logs

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs

-----> Node.js app detected

       

-----> Creating runtime environment

       

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

       NODE_VERBOSE=false

       NODE_ENV=production

       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

       

-----> Installing binaries

       engines.node (package.json):  ^14.0.0

       engines.npm (package.json):   >= 3.0.0

       

       Resolving node version ^14.0.0...

       Downloading and installing node 14.19.1...

       Bootstrapping npm >= 3.0.0 (replacing 6.14.16)...

       npm >= 3.0.0 installed

       

-----> Restoring cache

       - node_modules

       

-----> Installing dependencies

       Installing node modules

       

       added 402 packages, and audited 403 packages in 10s

       

       55 packages are looking for funding

         run `npm fund` for details

       

       3 high severity vulnerabilities

       

       Some issues need review, and may require choosing

       a different dependency.

       

       Run `npm audit` for details.

       

-----> Build

       Running heroku-postbuild

       

       > @tasting-organizer/server@0.4.0 heroku-postbuild

       > npm run compile

       

       

       > @tasting-organizer/server@0.4.0 compile

       > shx rm -rf lib/ && tsc

       

       

-----> Caching build

       - node_modules

       

-----> Pruning devDependencies

       

       up to date, audited 192 packages in 1s

       

       13 packages are looking for funding

         run `npm fund` for details

       

       3 high severity vulnerabilities

       

       Some issues need review, and may require choosing

       a different dependency.

       

       Run `npm audit` for details.

       

-----> Build succeeded!

-----> Discovering process types

       Procfile declares types     -> (none)

       Default types for buildpack -> web

-----> Compressing...

       Done: 34.4M

-----> Launching...

       Released v7

       https://tasting-organizer.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

If I run the scripts locally, everything works.

I just run the steps manually in heroku console.
Strangely `tsc` doesn't emit anything but `tsc --showConfig` shows the config I want.
I don't understand why it doesn't emit the files.  I even added `--noEmit false` to no avail.

Why are the compiled files not in `/app/lib/`?
Any ideas?

Comment: Provide the build.log

Comment: I added the build.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, although I'm not really sure as to why it is the solution.

1. add `./lib` to `exclude` in `tsconfig.json`

```
"exclude": [
    "test",
    "lib"
  ]
```

2. don't delete the `lib` folder before building
   In my case change `"compile": "shx rm -rf lib/ && tsc"` to `"compile": "tsc"`

Now it works.